# DiveintoHTML5.info is based on?

Tags: html, css

I was wondering what programming/markup languages does [Diveintohtml5.info](http://diveintohtml5.info) use. I am planning to create an online book(on some math stuff) similar to that of Mark Pilgrims' but need to know what exactly he used to create them.
Did he use a CMS like wordpress? Or it's just plain old HTML and CSS?

I am a bit new to the world of web development. Be kind.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ask them: http://whois.domaintools.com/diveintohtml5.info

Comment: Looking at https://github.com/diveintomark/diveintohtml5 it seems that it is just HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [the book’s source code on GitHub](https://github.com/diveintomark/diveintohtml5), it seems to be mostly static HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. However, it uses Python, Java, and shell code too, as you can see in [the `Makefile`](https://github.com/diveintomark/diveintohtml5/blob/master/Makefile). (`Makefile`s are run with [`make`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_%28software%29).)

The `Makefile` contains a lot of shell code doing things like substitution, file copying, and concatenation. It also calls the Python and Java code, which is all in the [`util`](https://github.com/diveintomark/diveintohtml5/tree/master/util) folder. The Python and Java programs compress the HTML and CSS, build the table of contents from the headings in each file, and do a few other things.